# c++ multithread code setting priority level to different threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to increase thread priority in pthreads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649281/how-to-increase-thread-priority-in-pthreads)

I have a multithread code written in C++ using pthread. basically I have a main thread doing critical work and another thread doing maintenance. I'm wondering if there is a way to set a lower priority in the second thread so it runs when the first one is not busy?

Comment: You can set priority for sure, but with multi-core systems the way they are today, I doubt you'd need to for such a simple example.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[pthread_setschedparam](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_setschedparam.3.html)** to set the priority of the thread

Comment: Please avoid using references to "die" web site. It is outdated, bloated with ads, and appear as a first result only due to SEO.

Comment: thanks, I read the documents. looks like in user space I can use SCHED_BATCH or SCHED_IDLE to set a lower priority. I'm wondering what's the difference between the two? is it SCHED_OTHER > SCHED_BATCH > SCHED_IDLE?