# Increase thread quantum from user-mode

Tags: c, linux, kernel

Is it possible on Linux kernel 3.0+ to increase thread's quantum from user-mode? How?

Comment: This answer might be relevant:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/3663250/131930

Comment: "SCHED_FIFO is a simple scheduling algorithm without time slicing." http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/sched_setscheduler.2.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt it's possible. I quickly found this page ( http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/thread_scheduling_2.shtml ) which suggests that a thread's quanta length is variable anyway, and subject to many attributes of the execution environment.

I suppose if you really needed to it should be possible to write a kernel module that alters it, but then you're entering painful territory.

What are you doing that needs longer quanta lengths anyway? Maybe there's an alternative approach.

Comment: Well, all I need is to prevent preemption for some time.

Comment: That sounds like you're wanting to develop a real-time application for Linux.

Comment: Note that simply lengthening a thread's quantum wouldn't prevent pre-emption -- a thread can still be pre-empted at any time by a higher-priority thread, even if its quantum wasn't expired yet.  As David says, what you are asking for is real-time behavior, which is available (well, soft-real-time anyway) in Linux via sched_setscheduler().