# Given using C++ or C, how could I measure how long it takes to do a thread switch under linux?Is it possible?

Tags: c++, linux-kernel, scheduler, scheduling, schedule

Given using C++ or C, how could I measure how long it takes to do a thread switch under linux?Is it possible? At most platform, how long does it takes?Could anybody give me some typical value?

**I don't wanna to measure thread quantum indeed**. I hope to find a practical method to measure the duration of swithing a thread to another(**not how long a thread could run**).

I would appreciate that if you could provide the code.

I would be grateful for any hint on this question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42899151/thread-quantum-how-to-compute-it

Comment: Using elapsed CPU ticks?

Comment: @m0skit0  Either ticks or real wall clock is ok.

Comment: Ok, then use that?

Comment: It's at your choice.Either of them is ok to me.

Comment: @selbie Thank you.I would see it right now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Thread Quantum: How to compute it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42899151/thread-quantum-how-to-compute-it)

Comment: @d.olinger & selbie  I don't think so. **I don't wanna to measure thread quantum indeed**. I hope to find a practical method to measure the duration of swithing a thread to another(not how long a thread could run).

Answer (score 1):

See you again :)

It is possible, but you need to do a little change about kernel code. So openwrt or something else may be good for you.

You can see my [blog](https://ty-chen.github.io/linux-kernel-schedule/#more) and the [source code](https://code.woboq.org/linux/linux/kernel/sched/fair.c.html#4040) to solve the problem. The preemption schedule will do the time check, and it is like below

```
/*
 * Preempt the current task with a newly woken task if needed:
 */
static void
check_preempt_tick(struct cfs_rq *cfs_rq, struct sched_entity *curr)
{
    unsigned long ideal_runtime, delta_exec;
    struct sched_entity *se;
    s64 delta;
    ideal_runtime = sched_slice(cfs_rq, curr);
    delta_exec = curr->sum_exec_runtime - curr->prev_sum_exec_runtime;
    if (delta_exec > ideal_runtime) {
        resched_curr(rq_of(cfs_rq));
        /*
         * The current task ran long enough, ensure it doesn't get
         * re-elected due to buddy favours.
         */
        clear_buddies(cfs_rq, curr);
        return;
    }
    /*
     * Ensure that a task that missed wakeup preemption by a
     * narrow margin doesn't have to wait for a full slice.
     * This also mitigates buddy induced latencies under load.
     */
    if (delta_exec < sysctl_sched_min_granularity)
        return;
    se = __pick_first_entity(cfs_rq);
    delta = curr->vruntime - se->vruntime;
    if (delta < 0)
        return;
    if (delta > ideal_runtime)
        resched_curr(rq_of(cfs_rq));
}
```

Here we have several time helpful for you

ideal_runtime : the time this task run in this schedule period

sum_exec_runtime : total time the task run

prev_sum_exec_runtime : history total time

Comment: Chen, glad to see you, too.Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: You're welcome. If you have any other problems maybe we can talk about them.

Comment: If i understand you correctly, it could not be done under user space without modifying any kernel source code, because you could not know when the current thread begins to be switched out at all.Am i right?

Comment: You're right, you need to add some little function in kernel, or maybe there are some functions can do it in user space but I don't know. I think ptrace may work but I haven't try it so I'm not sure.