# How to specify thread priority?

Tags: embedded-linux, vala

I need to run multiple threads on an embedded-linux target. 
One of the threads requires a lot of resources so I need it to run in background at a low priority. 
There will be times when the higher priority threads will have nothing to do. A typical vala `Thread.create` looks like this:

```
Thread.create<void*> (pProcessor->run, true);
```

Is there a way to specify the thread priority?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the threading stuff in GLib, you would have to use pthreads directly.  There is some information on how to do that in C [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649281/how-to-increase-thread-priority-in-pthreads).  You would also need to create Vala bindings for the relevant functions since nobody has done so yet (it's pretty easy... if you understand how Vala maps to C it would only take a couple minutes).

If I were you I would look into using a priority queue instead.  If you don't feel like writing your own [bump](http://code.google.com/p/bump/) should already have everything you need (specifically, [Semaphore](http://code.coeusgroup.com/bump/valadoc/bump-0.1/Bump.Semaphore.html) and/or [TaskQueue](http://code.coeusgroup.com/bump/valadoc/bump-0.1/Bump.TaskQueue.html)), or [AsyncPriorityQueue](http://code.coeusgroup.com/bump/valadoc/bump-0.1/Bump.AsyncPriorityQueue.html) if you would prefer to work at a lower level.