# on Android, What value to set in thread.priority and thread.policy for a background thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, delphi, firemonkey

Under Android i create a thread, and i want to set it's priority to around 5% of the mainthread. However i see that on posix 2 properties, Thread.priority and thread.policy, that are both integer, and i don't know what value to put in each fields. The delphi doc is quite empty about this.

Comment: This might help... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649281/how-to-increase-thread-priority-in-pthreads

Comment: Delphi documentation is wrong place to look for OS specifics. https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/threads.html

Comment: @Deltics i try to set Policy to SCHED_BATCH but seam to change nothing, also did i need to set it before the thread is running or after ? and they not say what value to use for priority :(

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar unfortunatly developer.android.com/topic/performance/threads.html  don't speak about policy/priority :(

Comment: Point is you will not find OS specific information in Delphi doc. You have to search Android documentation for right answers.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar i know but i don't find :( on android they don't speak about thread policy/priority :( and i m affraid that my problem is not only related to priority but with also how the memory manager work in multithread

Comment: It is not clear what your problem is and what you are trying to achieve. Giving some context around your question would be desirable. As is, it is either unclear or too broad.