# Does greater decimal value mean higher priority or low priority for a process?

Tags: operating-system

For example P1 has priority 2 and P2 has priority 5. Which process has higher priority? Which process will be executed first?

Comment: It would depend on the operating system.

Comment: ..and on the OS state at the time.  If there are two cores free, both may be executed, no matter what those priority numbers actually mean.

Comment: In some systems, there is an internal and an external priority. The user might see priority 31 as the highest priority while internally, priority 31 is priority 0.

Answer (score 0):

This very much depends on the underlying operating system.

See

- [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686277(v=vs.85).aspx) for Windows
- or [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649281/how-to-increase-thread-priority-in-pthreads) for Linux
- or [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/CreatingThreads/CreatingThreads.html) for Mac OS
  ...

and so on. In other words: the answer is that you do some research for the operating system you intend to work with.

Comment: I have to solve CPU scheduling questions in my exams and there will be specified the operating system.

Comment: Actually our course is not specified for any particular OS. We study generally that what are the functionalities of an OS.