# How to set in proper way priority of one of two threads using pthreads

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

Example. I want to share `getFrame` and `processFrame` in seperated threads.
I think that I will make two threads for every action, but I still doesn't know how to set properly priority of threads I mean, I would like to have more priority  for `getFrame`  thread than `processFrame`, but If I have only two threads than I can set a priority for `getFrame` after created this thread, so the priority will be working after done action  by everyone threads. How can I solve it?
Maybe I could create a main thread which will make another two threads for `getFrame` and `processFrame` and then I set a priority for `getFrame` thread?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649281/how-to-increase-thread-priority-in-pthreads) help?

Comment: Are you talking about the scheduling priority?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to change priority of threads to handle events.. to me it looks like a design of system is very weak.

While designing system it's better never to assume thread priority as it could change from system to system based on settings.

Why don't you send an event to other thread and wait for ack back.